# Generate C# class from XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

Can I generate a C# class from an XML file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate .NET 4.0 classes from xsd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217665/how-to-generate-net-4-0-classes-from-xsd)

Answer (score 371, accepted):

Yes, by using [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx)

```
D:\temp>xsd test.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'D:\temp\test.xsd'.

D:\temp>xsd test.xsd /classes
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'D:\temp\test.cs'.
```

**Notes**

Answer [how to change directory in Developer Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065421/command-prompt-wont-change-directory-to-another-drive) to d:\temp may be useful.

If you generate classes for multi-dimensional array, there is a bug in XSD.exe generator, but [there are workarounds](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2219).

Comment: To use `xsd` run the **Developer Command Prompt for VS2013** under your tools menu.

Comment: `xsd.exe` can be found under: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows`

Comment: be warned if you have a large complex XML file the class generated will be so ugly that it will almost be unusable ;)

Comment: For me `xsd.exe` was found at: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools`

Comment: I have a 7GB XML file (it is being used as a human-readable transform of a binary data transfer mechanism in this case) and xsd.exe runs out of memory trying to read that pretty quickly.  Note that this is not an out of memory condition on the machine itself; there is plenty of RAM in this machine (192GB) and xsd.exe uses no more than 4 before it dies.  So this solution won't be the answer for everyone.

Comment: @Naikrovek Yeah and XML is not for everything.  :)

Answer (score 482):

If you are working on .NET 4.5 project in VS 2012 (or newer), you can just **Special Paste** your XML file as classes.

1. Copy your XML file's content to clipboard
2. In editor, select place where you want your classes to be pasted
3. From the menu, select `EDIT > Paste Special > Paste XML As Classes`

Comment: I just wish this generated auto-implemented properties, like it does for "Paste JSON as Classes". Currently this means a 6 fold bloated code result, which is a lot harder to read. This alone makes me look for another tool, unfortunately.

Comment: Was this left out of VS 2013?

Comment: @Roger I haven't used VS 2013, but I think this feature should be there, make sure your project is targeting .NET 4.5 Framework

Comment: This is much quicker than `xsd`, but the output is about the same.

Comment: I have only "Paste JSON as Classes"

Comment: @Elaine are you sure you are working on NET 4.5 project? Your projects property 'Target framework' should be set to .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: @miszczu, it's just solved with pointing to any class in WCF project other than class library.

Comment: This is soo helpfull! One addition: You must first create a class (like class1.cs and do the paste special in there. After this action, you can rename to the desired name.

Comment: I would like the text *Copy your XML file to clipboard* to modified to **Copy your XML file's content to clipboard**. Because that way I was able to make it work. Else the option show as disabled.

Comment: Awesome solution! On top of this if you have Resharper - CTRL+ALT+F (Full cleanup) also makes the generated code readable.

Comment: as @Jess mentioned the output is nearly the same as running `xsd` -- I noticed pasting omits `XmlElementAttribute(Form = ...Unqualified)`; but I actually don't know if that matters...

Comment: Hi @drzaus.  Funny I was just using `xsd` the other day.  This time it was very useful b/c the XML was huge and I can do schema validation.

Comment: good call @Jess, schema validation is an important point; also mentioned by Albin's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4203765/1037948

Comment: If you don't have resharper use regex replace with `public (\w+) (\w+)\r\n +\{\r\n +get\r\n +\{\r\n +return this.*;\r\n +\}\r\n +set\r\n +\{\r\n +this.*;\r\n +\}\r\n +\}\r\n` => `public $1 $2 { get; set; }` and `        private \w+ \w+Field;\r\n\r\n`

Comment: If you have an xsd file, open XML Schema Explorer window. Then right click to the root element and click Generate Sample Xml and do the above Special Paste. It works so simple.

Comment: It generates nice classes with many attributes correctly set as boolean, integer, float but it does not work properly in some cases. It sdoes not work for me when I have <ElementA xsi:type="MyElementA" ... >. The error using XML Deserialize is "MyElementA not defined" (or similar). Only using xsd.exe I have all the proper classes defined correctly and XML deserialization works. Unfortunately all the properties are set as string (you have just to change the type manually in the generated class) and many elelemts are defined as array (again manual changes to have only one element).

Comment: There is minor difference to XSD output. Special Paste generate numbers automatically, xsd.exe not.

Comment: this is nice and easy but say that you are getting xml reply from some http call. And in that particular xml a certain values are always 2 digit (for sake of example) the "paste" will make that field `byte` or `short`. And then one day, you call the rest api and in you get a well formed xml, but that value is all of sudden 123456789. I think everyone gets where I'm going ;)

Answer (score 62):

At first I thought the Paste Special was the holy grail!  But then I tried it and my hair turned white just like the Indiana Jones movie.

But now I use http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ and now I'm as young as ever.

Here's a segment of what it generated:

```
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="entry")]
    public class Entry {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="hybrisEntryID")]
        public string HybrisEntryID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="mapicsLineSequenceNumber")]
        public string MapicsLineSequenceNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: The output of this tool is nice, but I just want to make throw a word of caution out there not to submit any sensitive data to this site (or any other for that matter). While I appreciate the service that is offered, there is no privacy policy and little to no assurance that what you paste won't be logged and examined, etc.

Comment: I had an xml file that has some recursive relations (maybe it's called circular relation, I'm not sure.) The others failed but http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ was very successful on that xml.

Comment: @D.Kermott thanks for the website link, I've had a quick look at it and it looks like it does a much better job than the paste special, the code looks cleaner, though my test xml created more classes, it was much nicer to use.

Comment: Pity it seems to invert the order of classes (outside elements listed last)

Comment: Just want to point out that this tool doesn't properly set the [Form property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.form?view=net-6.0) of the `XmlElement` attribute. This make the standard .NET xml serializer fail silently (no error, but creates an empty object). So if the xml mix elements with and without namespaces, you will need to update the code accordingly. The xsd.exe tool handles this properly.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem as you so I decided to write my own program.

The problem with the "xml -> xsd -> classes" route for me was that it just generated
a lump of code that was completely unmaintainable and I ended up turfing it.

It is in no way elegant but it did the job for me.
You can get it here: [SimpleXmlToCode](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexmltocode/)

Please make suggestions if you like it.

Comment: produces wrong code:


  // ELEMENTS
  [XmlIgnore]
  public DateTime Value { get; set; }

  [XmlText]
  public string ValueString
  {
   get { return Value ? "true" : "false"; }
   set { Value = value == "true"; }
  }

Comment: And the constructors are unnecessary + you should include comments for publicly visible members

Comment: In my defense it was something I slapped together very quickly which worked for me. I haven't gone back to it but feel free to contribute to the repo any changes.

Comment: I've been using this for a few months - it's not perfect, but it's quite useful and I find it generates much more readable/simpler XML than VS2013's paste as XML. Much appreciated Talon.

Answer (score 6):

You should consider svcutil ([svcutil question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245896/is-svcutil-exe-a-replacement-for-xsd-exe))

Both xsd.exe and svcutil operate on the XML schema file (.xsd).  Your XML must conform to a schema file to be used by either of these two tools.

Note that various 3rd party tools also exist for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use xsd as suggested by Darin.

In addition to that it is recommended to edit the test.xsd-file to create a more reasonable schema.

`type="xs:string"` can be changed to `type="xs:int"` for integer values
`minOccurs="0"` can be changed to `minOccurs="1"` where the field is required
`maxOccurs="unbounded"` can be changed to `maxOccurs="1"` where only one item is allowed

You can create more advanced xsd-s if you want to validate your data further, but this will at least give you reasonable data types in the generated c#.

Answer (score 2):

Use below syntax to create schema class from XSD file.

```
C:\xsd C:\Test\test-Schema.xsd /classes /language:cs /out:C:\Test\
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this site a bit ago.  It converts XML and JSON to C# and Java classes.  Has several options to tweak as you need.  I use it pretty often.
https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp

Answer (score 0):

To convert XML into a C# Class:

- Navigate to the Microsoft Visual Studio Marketplace: 
  -- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com
- In the search bar enter text:
  -- xml to class code tool
- Download, install, and use the app

Note: in the fullness of time, this app may be replaced, but chances are, there'll be another tool that does the same thing.