# How can I convert an XSD file to C# Class

Tags: c#, xsd, servicestack

I have a file in XSD format. How can I convert it to a C# class?

I need class reference in other web applications where I need to make post call as per below:

```
var res = client.Post<Customer>("/customers", c );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate .NET 4.0 classes from xsd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217665/how-to-generate-net-4-0-classes-from-xsd)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the [XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) `xsd.exe` found in your framework tools to convert your schema into a serializable class or dataset.

```
xsd file.xsd {/classes | /dataset} [/element:element]
         [/language:language] [/namespace:namespace]
         [/outputdir:directory] [URI:uri]
```

And in example, whereas the C# class will be generated in the same directory as the xsd tool:

```
xsd /c YourFile.xsd
```

Comment: you do need a `/c` or `/classes` in your command, note - and you *don't* need the language, since c# is the default

Comment: @George I need C# code to generate this using above link directly , is it possible or i need to do it after downloading that XSD first?

Comment: Might be useful if you knew the location https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975031/where-to-find-xsd-exe-in-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-8

Comment: In case you have imported another .xsd from a main .xsd file, we can do like this: `xsd file.xsd import1.xsd import2.xsd /c`

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this...

```
  <xsd xmlns='http://microsoft.com/dotnet/tools/xsd/'>
<generateClasses language='CS' namespace='Namespace.subnamespace'>
    <schema>FirstSchema.xsd</schema>
    <schema>AnotherSchema.xsd</schema>
    <schema>LastSchema.xsd</schema>
</generateClasses>
</xsd>
```

Comment: I like where this is going, but can you explain what is reading this file, or how it produces the resulting C# files?

Comment: for details on how to use the advanced parameter file see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx