# where to find xsd.exe in visual studio 2013 on windows 8

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, schema, xsd.exe

I have used the xsd.exe utility in `Visual Studio 2003` and `2008` to generate typed datasets from a 3rd party XSD file.  The third party has changed their schema so I need to regenerate the datasets but I can't find `XSD.EXE`.

The win8 search gives me information about the utility but not where it is, I tried a search in Windows explorer and didn't get any results.

I read posts regarding `Win7/VS 2008` that say it is part of the WinSDK but I can't find it in that folder either.

Some poster say it now needs to be downloaded but from where.  I am running `64 bit Windows 8 pro` and `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate`.

Answer (score 78):

Once you have the [SDK installed *](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK#Versions) (either Manually, or with Visual Studio), you'll find it in the following directories:

**SDK 8 and later**

There is an an additional FX version subdirectory:

```
%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\{ver}\bin\{FXVer} Tools
```

Where

- `{ver}` is the SDK version (e.g. `v8.1A`)
- and `{FXVer}` is the applicable .Net Framework version, e.g. `NETFX 4.0v`

**e.g.**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools
```

**SDK 7 and lower**

```
%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\{ver}\Bin\
```

Where `{ver}` is the SDK version (e.g. `v7.0A`)

On a **[32 bit O/S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594066/how-to-get-program-files-x86-env-variable)**, replace `%programfiles(x86)%` with `%programfiles%`

`*` Wikipedia maintains a fairly recent set of download links to the various SDK versions - scroll to the bottom of the table for recent ones.

Comment: For quick reference, on Win 7, the .NET 4 version of the XSD tool is found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools" (given that windows is installed at the default location)

Comment: Win10 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx

... all the documentation you want on how to use it - none on where to find it! Good job MS! *facepalm*

Comment: I found that it was insufficient to have just the Windows xxx SDK installed. I added the "Games and Graphics" individual component "Unreal Engine installer", which pulled in a bunch of other individual components. Only then did "...SDKs\Windows\v10.0A..." path show up with the corresponding xsd.exe installed. Not sure which of those components actually caused this to exist.

Answer (score 5):

This is part of the Windows SDK.  I know that you can download the Windows 7 SDK for .NET 4.0 and the files will be installed and will be fully functional on Windows 8. (It is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows?version?\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools where version will be OS version like v8 or similar)

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279
```

You may also find the xsd application as part of the full SDK.

```
For Windows 8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx
For Windows 8.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your environment variable `PATH`:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2
>   Tools

- Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\`
- Click latest version (e.g. `v10.0A`)
- Click `Bin`
- Select latest .NET Version e.g. `NETFX 4.7.2 Tools`
- There is `xsd.exe`

Run via command line using `xsd /c filename.xsd`

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio installed, then you may locate Developer Command Prompt (it is a shortcut in Start menu, or it should be available from VS IDE). A cmd window opens and you are able to run xsd.exe from it.

Answer (score -1):

Someone has posted a zip file with xsd.exe (from 2011) and xsd.exe.config on his personal web site:

(https://juliankay.com/development/download-xsd-exe/).

Download of the [zipfile](http://juliankay.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/xsd.zip) worked for me in 03/2017 .

Output (on Linux, with Mono Support built into the kernel):

```
/home/knut/bin/xsd.exe /?
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3038]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

xsd.exe -
    Utility to generate schema or class files from given source.
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to use an exe without license, and / or with the risk of malware?

Comment: Yes. As far as I remember, the xsd.exe is a small binary and It is part of an earlier release of the Resource Kit which used to have a liberal license. - Downloading .exe files from some random site - that was and is quite common. - Malware checks are left as an exercise for the user.  (Try in a virtualised computer first).