# TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "xsd.exe". The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visualgdb

In the intent of converting a Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (VS2015) project with VisualGDB to VS2017 without VisualGDB, I get the following error:

Notes: VS2017 includes a native feature for remote build/debugging.

> TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "xsd.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.

**Why is that happening and how to solve it?**

---

## More details

Opening the project with VS2017 and going to the properties, most of the required settings for remote build are missing. I tried to add/modify the ``.vcxproj` xml to match an new empty project which seem to build correctly remotely.

After this step, the property window of the project seem pretty similar, except an additional `XML Data generator Tool` section in the not-working project.

When building the project, it shows the following:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: project, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Cleaning remote project directory
1>TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "xsd.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.
1>
1>
1>Done building project "project.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

EDITED: it seem related with the inclusion of some sources like:

```
<Xsd Include="C:\Users\...\xml_file.xsd" />
```

Comment: A hint of where this xsd.exe is used would already be great

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue and resolved it through a combination of the following two steps:

- Locating `xsd.exe` on my file system. If it doesn't exist (although it should when Visual Studio is installed), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27223055/5040168) might help.
- Adding the path it is in to the "Executable Directories" [variable in the properties of the Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51440784/5040168). (Personally, I don't have Visual Studio installed, so I added `<ExecutablePath>` properties next to the `<IncludePath>` ones in the .vcxproj file via text editor)