# Error TRK0005 Failed to locate: "fxc.exe". The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx-11

I am converting a visual studio c++ direct x project from visual studio 2017 to visual studio 2015. So far I have changed the project build tools to v140.

this is the current error message

[image]

fxc.exe is the Effect-Compiler Tool and according to msdn it should be located in (SDK root)\Utilities\Bin\x86. I am not sure how to find that location.

Comment: What Windows SDK are you trying to use to build this? VS 2017 defaults to using Windows 10 SDK 15063 or 16299 depending on your update, but VS 2015 can only use 14393 or earlier and typically defaults the Windows 8.1 SDK if you are writing a Win32 desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue, but the solution I finally implemented is more of a hack: It seems that VS2015 expands the Windows SDK environment variable to the Windows 7 SDK, which does not include fxc.

What I eventually did is adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64` to the "Executable Directories" variable under the "VC++ Directories" settings in the project properties. I do not like it, but it works ...