# xsd.exe: generate class for old schema (http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema)

Tags: c#, xsd

I have xsd schema with

> xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema" ...

I want to generate c# class for this schema but command

> xsd.exe my_xsd.xsd /classes

said

> "The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be  and its
>   namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'"

and as a result

> "Schema my_xsd.xsd  could not be validated"

I tried to change "2000/10" to "2001" but it fails too. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate .NET 4.0 classes from xsd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217665/how-to-generate-net-4-0-classes-from-xsd)

Comment: @MethodMan I have problem with namespace. It's not about "How to get c# class from xsd?"