# Generate code file from data table adapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, asp.net-webcontrol, datatableadapters

I'm working on an older `web site application` in C#, ASP.NET, which is now running on 4.7.2
The `WebControlling.xsd` contains the definitions, constraints and operations on the dataset with `tables` and `table adapters`.
For all the older tables there is a class operating on it as well as a view.
`.App_Code
- BLL
- - Foo.cs
- DAL
- - WebControlling.xsd
.Portal
- Foo
- - Foos.aspx
- - FooAdd.aspx
- - FooEdit.aspx`

The adapter has the regular `Fill` and `GetData` operations on it. Is there a way to generate some, if not all of this structure from the `.xsd` alone?
The other option I see is to copy and edit an existing class (like `Foo.cs`), but since all classes look the same I feel like they could be generated. I think it would be easier to use tooling if changes to this are necessery since it's less likely to fail and / or forget changes in some places.
This is what a `Foo.cs`looks like:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataObject]
public class Foo
{
    private FooTableAdapter _fooAdapter;
    public Foos()
    { 
    }

    protected FooTableAdapter Adapter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_FoosAdapter == null) _FoosAdapter = new FoosTableAdapter();
            return _FoosAdapter;
        }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
    public WebControlling.FoosDataTable GetFoos()
    {
        return Adapter.GetFoos();
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public WebControlling.FoosDataTable GetFooByID(Guid ID)
    {
        return Adapter.GetFooByID(ID);
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public WebControlling.FoosDataTable GetFoosByCountryID(Guid ID, bool viewAll)
    {
        String sViewAll = viewAll ? "1" : "0";

        return Adapter.GetFoosByCountryID(ID, sViewAll);
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public WebControlling.FoosDataTable GetOpenFoosByCountryID(Guid ID, bool viewAll)
    {
        String sViewAll = viewAll ? "1" : "0";

        return Adapter.GetOpenFoosByCountryID(ID, sViewAll);
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public WebControlling.FoosDataTable GetFoosWithForeignValues()
    {
        return Adapter.GetFoosWithForeignValues();
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public WebControlling.FoosDataTable GetFooByIDWithForeignValues(Guid ID)
    {
        return Adapter.GetFooByIDWithForeignValues(ID);
    }

    public bool AddFoo(System.Guid FooID, System.String Name, Int32 FooYear, System.Boolean IsValid)
    {
        WebControlling.FoosDataTable Foos = new WebControlling.FoosDataTable();
        WebControlling.FoosRow Foosrow = Foos.NewFoosRow();

        Foosrow.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        Foosrow.FooID = FooID;
        Foosrow.Name = Name;
        Foosrow.FooYear = FooYear;
        Foosrow.IsValid = IsValid;

        Foos.AddFoosRow(Foosrow);
        int rowsAffected = Adapter.Update(Foos);

        return rowsAffected == 1;
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Update, true)]
    public bool UpdateFoo()
    {
        ...
    }


    public bool UpdateFooState(System.Guid ID, bool IsClosed)
    {
        ...
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Delete, true)]
    public bool DeleteFoo(Guid ID)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Seems generated to me.
Edit:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217665/how-to-generate-net-4-0-classes-from-xsd) has interesting insight into generating classes from `.xsd`. My question differs because:

- I'm looking for a way to also generate view in `.aspx`
- I'm looking to only generate one additional class, not the whole file again

Comment: Class Foo isn't generated, it's hand-written, a variation on [this classic approach to N-tiers with DataSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/creating-a-business-logic-layer-cs).

Comment: Thank you for this insight, I thought `BLL` and `DAL` were custom names.

Comment: @wazz, again the answer. You might need to add, that this methods could or should match the `.xsd` file

Comment: True, although they *have to* or you'll get an error. :o Thanks for feedback.