# Is it possible to de-serialize xml based on XSD scheme instead of paste special the results?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, xsd

My goal is to implement an api to an external webservice resource, the response format is xml and the scheme is also known.

For example, this is the external resource api:

https://MyProduct.MyDomain.com/webservice/rest/1.0/MyMethod/

And the external resource api's xml scheme:

https://MyProduct.MyDomain.com/xsd/1.0/MyMethodDataTypes.xsd

The xsd is very long and complex, so I would like to avoid copy it by hand into a class response

So in order to de-serialize the response this is what I did:

1. Using Postman I've requested a demo request.
2. Copied the xml response.
3. Using visual studio paste special, I've pasted the xml response as a class.

The problem is that now the class response is built upon only one specific request and does not contain all of the response properties.

So my question is:

Is it possible to create the response class based on the vendor's xsd scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible at the command prompt.

**xsd.exe your.xsd /classes**

The xsd.exe could be usually found along the following location:

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\xsd.exe"

Lots of additional info could be found here: [How to generate .NET 4.0 classes from xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217665/how-to-generate-net-4-0-classes-from-xsd)