# How do I change my current directory location from C drive to D drive in git bash

Tags: git-bash

How do I change my current directory location from /c/users/XYZ to D:college stuff in git bash

Answer (score 3):

Git bash stores the system Drive as folder, so say for example if in your system there is 3 drives namely C, D and E Drive. so what git bash will do is, it will create directly like structure, so say for example, currently, you are in

```
C:/users/hitesh/gitRepo
```

and You want to navigate to

```
D:/Repos/gitRepoFirst
```

then you can simply do like bellow

```
cd D:
```

Then, this will make you move in into
D Drive and then you can navigate as usual, but there is pretty handy way to directly get into your destination folder(D:/Repos/gitRepoFirst in this example), you can do like bellow

```
cd D:/Repos/gitRepoFirst and press enter
```

Cheersssssssss!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can change it by typing the drive letter and directory name in your bash and hit enter:-

```
$ cd /D/folder_name
```

and then you will switch to that drive and directory. Here D is the Drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

3 years later I found that post.. but did it work for you? Are you sure you are in Git Bash and not Git CMD? the above solutions does not work in Git CMD though..
there is a good explanation in another stckoverflow post here:

[Command prompt won't change directory to another drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065421/command-prompt-wont-change-directory-to-another-drive)

fast answer from this post:

```
cd /d d:\Docs\Java
```

CHDIR [/D] [drive:][path] CHDIR [..] CD [/D] [drive:][path] CD [..]

.. Specifies that you want to change to the parent directory.