# How to change the build agent work location to other location from teamcity server

Tags: batch-file, teamcity, build-agent

I invoked  the bat from teamcity server. Below is the log.
In the bat which has to change directory location to what I have mentioned in the `cd`.

```
Starting:C:\AUTOEBCDeployment\Autodeploy.bat
in directory: D:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity BuildAgent\work\8a77def6c3e16d10
D:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity BuildAgent\work\8a77def6c3e16d10>cd C:\AUTOEBCDeployment\dist
D:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity BuildAgent\work\8a77def6c3e16d10>for /F "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /a-d *.zip') do set DIST_FILE=%a 
File Not Found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Prompt Won't Change Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065421/command-prompt-wont-change-directory)

Comment: @Melebius Remove the prompt text so we can see the code. Screen shots don't have code attribute and are unnecessary

Comment: @ACatInLove The paths could be shortened but it is important to keep the information (which [your suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18496558) removed) that the command is used to change the drive. Moreover, this question seems to be duplicate, so it does not deserve the care to make it perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set "Working directory" in your build step

[image]

Or you can change the agent property. Open **buildagent.property** file and change the parameter `workDir=C:\AUTOEBCDeployment\dist`

Answer (score 0):

Had you read the help information from `CD /?` you'd have spotted the correct syntax is:

```bat
CD /D "C:\AUTOEBCDeployment\dist"
```

*The doublequotes are optional but recommended.*