# How to change the default directory of PowerShell in Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: python, powershell, conda

I am using Anaconda Navigator version 1.9.12 for Windows 7, along with Python 3.7.6. I installed this recently to study Pytorch.

In order to free up space in my `C:\` drive, I created my main Pytorch folder in my `D:\` drive at the address of :

`D:\Pytorch_folder\Pytorch`

However, every single time I open up Powershell Prompt through Anaconda, the default directory is always:

`C:\Users\Administrator`

Which happens to be the `%HOMEPATH%` environment variable. I've tried many suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304305/anaconda-python-change-anaconda-prompt-user-path) question, including changing the default start directory through `"Properties"`. I know I can access my folder using `cd` command, but it is annoying to do so every time.

Is there a way to change default directory for Powershell in Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, why do you want to change the default location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple fix that I found:

Go to `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\Documents` or whatever your default Document folder is. Then, create a directory, if it doesn't exist already, called `WindowsPowerShell`.

Inside, create a new file called `profile.ps1`.

Inside the file, type in this line of code:

`Set-Location "YOUR_FILE_PATH"`

Save the file, and restart the PowerShell interface.

Your default directory will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the path to **D:/** drive is one way. If that does not work, try re-installing, I know this sounds time-consuming, but I have faced a similar issue time and again.

Comment: So you mean reinstalling the entire Anaconda?

Comment: How **exactly** do I change the path to **D:/** drive though? Is it just what I did...changing the startup directory?

Comment: Yes. Since that did not work, you might have to reinstall.