# Changed Starting Path with PowerShell Profile But Cannot Change it Back

Tags: powershell

While learning Anaconda I had a problem with "cd" not working in Anaconda PowerShell, so I did what is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289618/how-to-change-the-default-directory-of-powershell-in-anaconda-navigator), manually created a profile and set the path to a specific folder. It worked.

But today somehow I found "cd" is working for me again, so I was going to delete that ps1 file. But the folder together with the file in that was no loner there, completely gone. Now I am stuck with my temporary path on every PowerShell start-up.

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1), `$profile` should return my profile variables, which it did:

```
C:\Users\myname\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

But first, this is not the file name I gave it; second, this path is also non-existent, both folder and file.

I tried `notepad $profile`, then Notepad told me "The system cannot find the path specified." But it is exactly the path the system told me.

Some answer I saw here says that is because my profile is non-existent, I need to create one first. That is not the case here. I definitely overwrote my starting path, but I cannot find the actual profile file to edit that back.

I also tried doing it [the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289618/how-to-change-the-default-directory-of-powershell-in-anaconda-navigator) again but changing `"YOUR_FILE_PATH"` into `"%Home"` hoping to "overwrite" it back, yet somehow this time it did not work and the file did not disappear as it did the first time.

I am really confused on this.

Comment: Try `$profile | get-member -name *user*` to list all candidate locations, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493662/5538420) why.

Comment: Hi @dxiv, I got the other locations in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1. But there is no file with that name in the folder.

Comment: The defaults PS starts with must come from one of those 4 files. If one is not present then it's not used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset PowerShell to the original settings when PowerShell was installed.

1. Uninstall PowerShell from the Add or Remove Programs.
2. Restart your computer.
3. Reinstall PowerShell.