# How to configure the directory Angular uses to creates apps?

Tags: angular-cli

I work in a corporate environment where everyone's document files are stored on a network share by default. As a developer, I'd like all source code files to be created locally where I can rule out issues regarding network resources and file permissions I have less control over.

I am new to Angular and am going through the "getting started" tutorial here: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart By using this command, "ng new NewApp01", I get warnings and errors.

[image: warnings and errors]

I'd like to configure Angular to use a directory on my C drive. I've tried using "ng init --source-dir" unsuccessfully:

[image]

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

UPDATE: From looking at the first two comments left so far, I've tried "ng new" again with "--directory":

[image]

Comment: i dont think 'init' is an angular-cli command. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

Comment: `ng new` is the command. Also use `--directory` not `--source-dir`. If you have permissions to `cd` to the directory, why don't you just do that? `cd C:\DARREN\CODE\DEV` then `ng new <my app>`.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I tried to do a CD to my CD drive (see 2nd screen shot) and it stayed on my U drive. :-/

Comment: It's on another drive. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065421/command-prompt-wont-change-directory-to-another-drive

Comment: That solved it. Thanks! How can I give you credit for the answer?