# serialize & deserialize with property as list<string> xml file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

How to serialize & deserialize below xml file using C#. 
I have created serializable class for this xml.

below some code to deserialize this xml, the list is able to get only single value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
<CSVFile>
<string>ff</string>
<string>gg</string>
<string>jj</string>
</CSVFile> 
</Configuration>


[Serializable, XmlRoot("Configuration"), XmlType("Configuration")]
public class Configuration
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        CSVFile = new List<string>();
    }

    [XmlElement("CSVFile")]
    public List<string> CSVFile { get; set; }
}

public class Mytutorial
{
    string configFilePath = "above xml file path"

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
    FileStream xmlFile = new FileStream(configFilePath, FileMode.Open);
    Configuration con = (Configuration)serializer.Deserialize(xmlFile);
 }
```

Comment: refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate C# class from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml)

Comment: Very interesting CSV file. Where are columns and where are rows? Is each `string` a line?

Answer (score 4):

Just change your class as below, it will work

```
public class Configuration
{
    [XmlArray("CSVFile")]
    public List<string> CSVFile { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your XML definition does not match your models.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <CSVFile>
    <csvstrings>ff</csvstrings>
    <csvstrings>gg</csvstrings>
    <csvstrings>jj</csvstrings>
  </CSVFile> 
</Configuration>
```

It requires the following models:

Configuration
CSVFile

So, your implementation should be:

```
[Serializable]
public class CSVFile
{
    [XmlElement("csvstrings")]
    public List<string> csvstrings { get; set; }

    public CSVFile()
    {

    }
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("Configuration"), XmlType("Configuration")]
public class Configuration
{
    public Configuration()
    {

    }

    [XmlElement("CSVFile")]
    public CSVFile csvs { get; set; }
}

public class Mytutorial
{
    string configFilePath = "above xml file path"

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
    FileStream xmlFile = new FileStream(configFilePath, FileMode.Open);
    Configuration con = (Configuration)serializer.Deserialize(xmlFile);
}
```

Comment: You changed the xml and also class definitions just to make it work.