# deserialize simple xml into List<string>

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I know it's a pretty stupid question, but I'm stuck... (similar question with no useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18311054/1538384))

my xml is

```
<Param>
    <MyList>
        <mynode>aaa</mynode>
        <mynode>bbb</mynode>
        <mynode>ccc</mynode>
        <mynode>ddd</mynode>
    </MyList>
</Param>
```

and I have a class like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlArray("MyList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("mynode")]
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

but when i try to deserialize i get a nullerrorexception

why this doesn't work?

**edit:**
deserialize code:

```
public static Param InitConfig(string Path)
{
    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xRoot.ElementName = "Param";
    xRoot.IsNullable = true;

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Param), xRoot);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path))
    {
        return (Param)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Param
{
    public MyClass MyClass {get; set;}
}
```

(actually more complex)

Comment: So what does not work? What is the error? What goes wrong?

Comment: Try filling out the class with sample data and serializing that - then you will see what deserialization expects as an input.

Comment: Can't touch the xml file... I have to figure out how to deserialize that structure in a List<string>

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the code that actually does the serialization it is hard to find the bug. However, you can try telling the serializer what is the top element of the xml:

```
[XmlRoot("Param")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlArray("MyList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("mynode")]
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
The serializer should be of type `MyClass`:

```
public static Param InitConfig(string Path)
{
    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xRoot.ElementName = "Param";
    xRoot.IsNullable = true;

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass), xRoot);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path))
    {
        return new Param {MyClass = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader)};
    }
}
```

Comment: this won't compile.`XmlElement` attribute cannot be applied to a `class`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `XmlRoot` attribute with `MyClass` like this:

```
[XmlRoot("Param")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlArray("MyList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("mynode")]
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use this code to `Deserialize` your xml:

```
XmlSerializer se = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
using(var stream = File.OpenRead("filePath"))
{
   var myClass = (MyClass) se.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one solution

```
        XmlSerializer rializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\t0408\\Desktop\\testfor.xml"))
        {
            MyClass myClass = (MyClass)rializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
```

// Class should be like this

```
        [XmlRoot("Param")]
         public class MyClass
         {
           [XmlArrayItem("mynode")]
           public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
         }
```

Thanks 
Lineesh