# RestSharp XML Deserialization into List

Tags: c#, xml, rest, restsharp

I am trying to deserialize the following xml using RestSharp, but I always get a list of null elements. I am new to REST based services and need some expert help! =)

**Solution Found**:     I figured it out. You have to explicitly tell RestSharp what kind of data is being deserialized:

```
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => {
                resp.ContentType = "application/json";
            };
```

Full XML: http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=San%20F&format=xml
Some of the XML is below:

```
<RESULTS>
<name>San Francisco, California</name>
<type>city</type>
<c>US</c>
<zmw>94101.1.99999</zmw>
<tz>America/Los_Angeles</tz>
<tzs>PDT</tzs>
<l>/q/zmw:94101.1.99999</l>
</RESULTS>
```

Here is my XMLResults class:

```
public class XMLResults
{
    public List<name> names {get; set;}
}
public class name 
{
    public string city {get; set;}
}
```

And here is my getWeather method:

```
public void getWeather(string query)
{
    var client = new RestClient ();
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    client.BaseUrl = "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com";
    request.Resource = "aq";
    request.AddParameter ("query", query);
    request.AddParameter ("format", "xml");
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
    var city = client.Execute<XMLResults>(request);
    Console.WriteLine (city.Data.names.Count); // Results in 20

}
```

Comment: We just released a new version of RestSharp (104.2). Can you try it with that and see if the problem persists?

Comment: I have the latest version. I am using Xamarin studio, so the component was installed using the in-built component store.

When I changed the POCO to just
`public class RESULTS 
 {
  public string name {get; set;}
 }`
I get the first name in the XML but none of the others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to explicitly tell RestSharp what kind of data is being deserialized: `request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json";};`

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would take a valid XML response ( like the one you posted ) and create a class from it using the xsd.exe program that comes with Visual Studio (it is VS Command Line Tool)

[Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml)

Then you can easily Serialize and Deserialize your Object.

Comment: I figured it out. You have to explicitly tell RestSharp what kind of data is being deserialized:    `request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => {
    resp.ContentType = "application/json";
   };`