# Deserialize XML in C# with the same name of attribute and element - reflection error

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, windows-8

I have a document with this kind of structure:

```
<page name="some-name">
    <header>
        //some content
    </header>
    <section header="value">
        //some content
    </section>
</page>
```

When I deserialize this document to get an instance of Page class, I always get reflection error and InvalidOperationException. I figured out by debugging and a lot of try and error that the reason for this error is that i have the same name for a node (XMLElement) and a property (XMLAttribute), in this example the name is "header". XML structure is not changeable in any way, so that is not the solution. Is there a way to make it work, or do I have to add the property value later, outside of deserialization?

Classes are in this form:

```
[XmlType("page")]
public class Page
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set }

    [XmlElement("header")]
    public Header Header { get; set }

    [XmlElement("section")]
    public Section Section { get; set }
}

[XmlType("section")]
public class Section
{
    [XmlAttribute("header")]
    public string Header { get; set }
}

[XmlType("header")]
public class Header
{
    //elements and attributes as properties
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[XmlRoot("page")]` to specify the name of generated xml root element instead of using `[XmlType("page")]`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate classes from XML using [Xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) and see how it manages to solve this. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml) is more info about classes generation from XML.