# C# XML Document Error (2,2) deserialize xml and storing to array

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

Aim:
 - Deserialize data from an xml document and storing it as an array.
 - Avoiding manually assigning the data to different strings. 
 - The xml document will be manually generated

```
public void DeserializeObject(string filename)
       {
           try
           {
               XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
               FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
               string[] XmlData = (string[])deserializer.Deserialize(fs);

               foreach (string p in XmlData)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(p);
               }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
           }   
       }
```

The XML document is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <software>Seiko</software>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <hardware>Martina</hardware>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Mapping>
```

Comment: Well your XML file isn't a string array - it's a serialized form of a `List<Product>` or something similar...

Comment: You have set the serializer to be a type of string[]. The resulting deserialized xml will not be a string array. It will be a object of type Mapping containing a Products object containing an array of Product objects etc. You need to build your class.

Comment: How can I best make it an array XML

Comment: @JerryMbawa XML cannot just be an array. There must be an enclosing type.

Comment: If you are using .Net framework 4.5 you can generate a type from xml as explained here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx                                                  Open a code file where the proxy is to be used. This file should be part of a .NET Framework 4.5 project.

Place the cursor in a location in the file outside any existing classes.

Select Edit, Paste Special, Paste XML as Classes. After generating the type from xml you can use it to deserialize your xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, found this solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Locations>
  <Location Name="Location1" IP="127.0.0.1"></Location>
  <Location Name="Location2" IP="127.0.0.1"></Location>
  <Location Name="Location3" IP="127.0.0.1"></Location>
  <Location Name="Location4" IP="127.0.0.1"></Location>
  <Location Name="Location5" IP="127.0.0.1"></Location>
</Locations>


using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           string[] strarr = GetStringArray("Locations.xml");

           foreach (string str in strarr)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(str);
           }
       }

       public static string[] GetStringArray(string url)
       {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);

           var locations = from l in doc.Descendants("Location")
                           select (string)l.Attribute("Name");

           return locations.ToArray();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication38
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<Mapping xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
              "<Products>" +
                "<Product>" +
                  "<software>Seiko</software>" +
                "</Product>" +
                "<Product>" +
                  "<hardware>Martina</hardware>" +
                "</Product>" +
              "</Products>" +
            "</Mapping>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Product").Select(x =>
                x.Elements().Select(y => new { type = y.Name, value = (string)y }).ToList()
            ).SelectMany(z => z).ToList();

            var groups = results.GroupBy(x => x.type).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Products are variable, they will be manually added, so it will not be good to define the product elements in the application, reason I wanted an array of the products

Comment: Will the product (ie hardware Martina) always be the first child after Product tag?

Comment: no, it could be anything, and could even change from hardware to (download Martina), so all the products elements are subject to change and they could be more than 2 products at a time

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a class from your sample XML. 
You can use the xsd.exe to generate a .xsd and from that create a .cs file.

The you need to add this type to your XmlSerializer

See this answer: [Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml)

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Mapping)); <- Created class type here.
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get the data form the XML-document as an array of strings, you can use XmlDocument to load in the data

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.xml");
```

Then you can find the nodes you need using an xPath expression:

```
XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes(...);
```