# Fill out an array from XML file using Serializable()

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am currently trying to deserialize an XML using the [Serializable()] command object and I am having some issue. Here is the code sample :

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace XmlManipulation
{
    public class XmlManip
    {
        public static TestCasesList SerializeTest() //test function
        {
            TestCasesList testslist = null;
            string path = @"C:\Users\sxtx2987\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FDB\deleteme\test.xml";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestCasesList));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

        testslist = (TestCasesList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
        return testslist;
        }
    }


    [Serializable()]
    public class TestCase
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("name")]
        public string name;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("objective")]
        public string objective;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("criteria")]
        public string criteria;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("issue")]
        public string issue;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("clientcomments")]
        public string clientcomments;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("authoritycomments")]
        public string authoritycomments;
    }

    [Serializable()]
    [XmlType("testcaseslist")]
    public class TestCasesList
    {
        [XmlArray("testcase")]
        public TestCase[] TestCase { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the file I am trying to deserialize

```
<xml version="1.00" encoding="UTF-8">
    <campaign>
        <name>Test XML</name>
        <number>XXXXXG04-06-1</number>
        <client>Fictional</client>
        <model>Rocket powered boots</model>
        <authority>Fictional authority</authority>
    </campaign>

    <testcaseslist>
        <testcase>
            <name>TestCase001</name>
            <objective>Objective test 1</objective>
            <criteria>Pass criteria test 1</criteria>
            <issue>Issue Description test 1</issue>
            <clientcomments>Client comments test 1</clientcomments>
            <authoritycomments>Authority comments test 1</authoritycomments>
        </testcase>

        <testcase>
            <name>TestCase002</name>
            <objective>Objective test 2</objective>
            <criteria>Pass criteria test 2</criteria>
            <issue>Issue Description test 2</issue>
            <clientcomments>Client comments test 2</clientcomments>
            <authoritycomments>Authority comments test 2</authoritycomments>
        </testcase>
    </testcaseslist>    
</xml>
```

What I am trying to achieve is taking all the roots element "testcase" and put each child element (namely : name,objective,criteria,issue,clientcomments,authoritycomments) in an class TestCasesList made of multiple classes TestCase.

So in this example :

TestCasesList

|-> testcase 1

|-> testcase 2

|-> etc....

which contains all the elements of the test case.

The code I have above is what I could gather up to now, but since this is quite a specific action that I am trying to do, I fail to find all the relevant information to solve my problem.

The code does not throw any errors, but when I try to call the function

```
        TestCasesList test = null;

        test = XmlManipulation.XmlManip.SerializeTest();
```

I get an empty test object.

I think that my problem is the XmlType and XmlArray section, but after a few hours of research and trials, I still cannot get the information from the XML.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

1. The root element may not be what you think it is.  Your code assumes that `<testcaseslist>` is the root element.  But in reality, the following is the root element:

   ```
   <xml version="1.00" encoding="UTF-8">
       <!-- XML Contents -->
   </xml>
   ```

   That root *looks like* a standard XML declaration:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
   ```

   But it's missing the question mark `<?xml>` at the beginning.  So you need to modify your code to deal with that.  You can do it by skipping forward to the appropriate element using an [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), or deserializing an appropriate container type.
2. Inside `<testcaseslist>` the elements `<testcase>` are not grouped under a container element.  Thus you need to use [`[XmlElement("testcase")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) not [`[XmlArray("testcase")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx).
3. To declare a root element name on a class, you must use [`[XmlRoot("testcaseslist")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) not [`[XmlType("testcaseslist")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx).

Thus your `TestCasesList` should look like:

```
[XmlRoot("testcaseslist")]
public class TestCasesList
{
    [XmlElement("testcase")]
    public TestCase[] TestCase { get; set; }
}
```

Then, to skip forward in your XML and deserialize the `<testcaseslist>` element, use [`XmlReader.ReadToFollowing()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162537.aspx):

```
    public static TestCasesList Deserialize(TextReader reader)
    {
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
        {
            // Skip to the <testcaseslist> element.
            if (!xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("testcaseslist", ""))
                return null;

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestCasesList));
            return (TestCasesList)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
```

Where `reader` is your `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);`.

Alternatively, using the container type:

```
[XmlRoot("xml")]
public class XmlRoot
{
    public TestCasesList testcaseslist { get; set; }
}
```

You could do:

```
    public static TestCasesList Deserialize(TextReader reader)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlRoot));
        var root = (XmlRoot)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return root == null ? null : root.testcaseslist;
    }
```

Some of the difficulties above could have been avoided by automatically generating your c# classes from your XML, e.g. with http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/.  For more see [Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml).

Incidentally, `[Serializable]` has no effect on `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations. After messing with the XML, I noticed that when I used that kind of structure for serialization, I could simply use the variable names and went with a structure without the [serializable] tags and simply used public variable for the serialization. Your explanations shed some lights on the mechanism of XML for me though. Thank you.