# How to return strongly typed objects instead of XElements when streaming an XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd, linq-to-xml

I would like to be able to return strongly typed objects instead of XElements from code that is streaming an XML document. Say the XML doc in question is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<People>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Adam</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  </Person>
</People>
```

Currently, my reader code looks like this:

```
public class PeopleReader
{
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamPerson(string path)
    {
        using (XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(path))
        {
            rdr.MoveToContent();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && rdr.Name == "Person")
                {
                    XElement item = XElement.ReadFrom(rdr) as XElement;

                    if (item != null)
                        yield return item;
                }
            }                  
        }
    }
}
```

The current calling code is:

```
// Current implementation
foreach (var person in PeopleReader.StreamPerson(@"...\People.xml"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(person.Element("LastName").Value);
}
```

where I have to call `.Element` and `.Value`.

What I  would like to have as calling code is:

```
// Required implementation where person is returned as a strongly typed obj.
foreach (var person in PeopleReader.StreamPerson(@"...\People.xml"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(person.LastName);
}
```

I understand that I can use xsd.exe to generate an .XSD file then generate .cs files, but I'm not clear on the actual steps. Also, I'm not sure how I would change my reader code to return the classes generated so the calling code receives strongly typed objects to enumerate? That is, how would I go from XElements to the strongly typed classes - Casting doesn't seem an option?

I am using VS2015, and would, if possible prefer to not have to use 3rd party tools.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: First you will need those strong types. Is it feasible to write them by hand, or must they be generated?

Comment: Hi @HenkHolterman, not feasible to do by hand. Generated is best. I only used a simple example here to convey my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use `XmlSerializer`.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

using (var rdr = XmlReader.Create(path))
{
    rdr.MoveToContent();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && rdr.Name == "Person")
        {
            yield return (Person) serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
        }
    }
}
```

Where your class is defined as below:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ovvupj) for a working demo.

To generate classes for your XML, you can either use `xsd.exe` (for either the XML or the XML Schema if you have one), or you can copy and paste a sample of the XML into Visual Studio using `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes`.  See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml).

Comment: Hi @Charles Mager, yes my file requires streaming. The example above was only cut down to convey message

Comment: I am not finding the Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes in my VS 2015 Professional. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found the Paste Special...! It doesn't appear when the active pane in VS is an XML doc that you've just copied from.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `IEnumerable<XElement>` create a type `Person` and return `IEnumerable<Person>`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And then return a new instance of it:

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamPerson(string path)
{
    using (XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(path))
    {
        rdr.MoveToContent();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            XElement item = XElement.ReadFrom(rdr) as XElement;
            if (item != null)
            {
                yield return new Person
                {
                    FirstName = item.Element("FirstName")?.Value,
                    LastName = item.Element("LastName")?.Value
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update** - After understanding that these xml represent a "lightweight" version of larger classes, and that the source code for those classes is referenced to the current project I suggest:

Create a base class to the larger classes containing the light-weight properties. This way you do not have code repetition and can cast from the one to the other.

```
public class PersonBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Person : PersonBase
{
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then do instantiate an object use either my approach above or the approach suggested by Charles

Comment: You have `if (item != null)` without declaring or initializing the `item` variable so I think `XElement item = XElement.ReadFrom(rdr) as XElement;` is missing from your snippet

Comment: Hi @Gilad Green, I will have lots of classes like Person some of which will be more complicated so I was looking to lean on some automated approach which I thought xsd might provide?

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Thanks, corrected. Accidentally removed it when copying rest of code from quesiton

Comment: @Cleve - Can you explain the use of these classes? Because if already creating the xsd then maybe generating the classes is good enough. Otherwise, depending on the usage of the data, maybe using `dynamic` will be helpful?

Comment: @GiladGreen - The classes are 'lightweight' versions of larger business objects to do some processing on rather than having to create the larger object graphs to do the same processing. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Cleve - Are those larger objects proper existing classes in your project?

Comment: @GiladGreen  - Sort of - In another project that the 'streaming' one has a reference to.

Comment: @GiladGreen Thanks for the update. Appreciate the responses. I think on balance Charles answer might be more applicable to my situation.