# Creating a model class for XML

Tags: c#, xml

How to create a model class for the below xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NOTIFICATION>
  <NOTIF_HEADER>
    <SOURCE>FCDB</SOURCE>
    <MSGID>585995798502256</MSGID>
    <TXN_ID>UTP</TXN_ID>
  </NOTIF_HEADER>
  <NOTIF_BODY>
    <UserDetail>
      <USER_NAME>Mr Customer</USER_NAME>
      <USER_EMAIL>MrCustomer@email.com</USER_EMAIL>
      <USER_MO>0500000007</USER_MO>
    </UserDetail>
    <CAS_Token>
      <PASS>
        <![CDATA[[PASS]]]>
      </PASS>
      <GEMALTO>N</GEMALTO>
    </CAS_Token>
  </NOTIF_BODY>
</NOTIFICATION>
```

I want to serialize this xml. For that I tried to create model class, but didn't worked.

Comment: Share what you tried, it can be refined here.

Comment: Did you google first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml

Answer (score 1):

Here is your class:

```
  /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class NOTIFICATION
    {

        private NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_HEADER nOTIF_HEADERField;

        private NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_BODY nOTIF_BODYField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_HEADER NOTIF_HEADER
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nOTIF_HEADERField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nOTIF_HEADERField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_BODY NOTIF_BODY
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nOTIF_BODYField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nOTIF_BODYField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_HEADER
    {

        private string sOURCEField;

        private ulong mSGIDField;

        private string tXN_IDField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string SOURCE
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sOURCEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sOURCEField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public ulong MSGID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mSGIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mSGIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string TXN_ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.tXN_IDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.tXN_IDField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_BODY
    {

        private NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_BODYUserDetail userDetailField;

        private NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_BODYCAS_Token cAS_TokenField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_BODYUserDetail UserDetail
        {
            get
            {
                return this.userDetailField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.userDetailField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_BODYCAS_Token CAS_Token
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cAS_TokenField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cAS_TokenField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_BODYUserDetail
    {

        private string uSER_NAMEField;

        private string uSER_EMAILField;

        private uint uSER_MOField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string USER_NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.uSER_NAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.uSER_NAMEField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string USER_EMAIL
        {
            get
            {
                return this.uSER_EMAILField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.uSER_EMAILField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public uint USER_MO
        {
            get
            {
                return this.uSER_MOField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.uSER_MOField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class NOTIFICATIONNOTIF_BODYCAS_Token
    {

        private string pASSField;

        private string gEMALTOField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PASS
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pASSField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pASSField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string GEMALTO
        {
            get
            {
                return this.gEMALTOField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.gEMALTOField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can generate in yourself with VS:

> **Edit** -> **Paste Special** -> **Paste XML as classes**