# Parse XML file and grab value from parent node

Tags: c#, .net, xml

XML file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

I need to read all data to my class:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Below code doesn't work, I can grab bookId from node, but not Title, Author..
How to achieve that result?   This is what I have so far:

```
const string filePath = @"C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\books.xml";

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

var dupa = xmlDoc
    .Descendants("book")
    .Select(x => new Book()
    {
        Id = (string) x.Attribute("bookid"),

        Title = (string) x.Attribute("title") // Title is empty after that code runs

    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Author, title etc. are descendant nodes of Book, not attributes.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is an [attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#dt-attr) of `<book>` but the other nodes are child XML [elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#dt-element) so you need to access them using [`XContainer.Element(XName name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx):

```
var dupa = xmlDoc
    .Descendants("book")
    .Select(x => new Book
    {
        Id = (string)x.Attribute("bookid"),
        Author = (string)x.Element("author"),
        Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
        Genre = (Genre)Enum.Parse(typeof(Genre), (string)x.Element("genre")),
        Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
        PublishDate = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
        Description = (string)x.Element("description"),
    }).ToList();
```

Here I am assuming that `Genre` is an enum that looks something like:

```
public enum Genre
{
    Computer,
    Fantasy,
};
```

Sample [fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ffqafQ).

Alternatively, you could create a `Catalog` type that contains your list of books, annotate it and `Book` with [attributes that control XML serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization), and deserializing everything using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Define your types like so:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "book")]
public class Book
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "genre")]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "publish_date")]
    public string PublishDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "catalog")]
public class Catalog
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "book")]
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public enum Genre
{
    Computer,
    Fantasy,
};
```

And then deserialize as follows:

```
List<Book> dupa;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Catalog));
    dupa = ((Catalog)serializer.Deserialize(reader)).Books;
}
```

Sample [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CqSRAV).

Notes:

- Consider changing `Genre` from an `enum` to a `string`.  With your current model, deserialization will fail if new genres are later added to the XML.
- There are a variety of tools to auto-generate types from XML that are compatible with `XmlSerializer`.  I used https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ and then modified the property names and types as required.  Another option is [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx).  For more see [Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203540).