# Deserialize a xml file with child elements in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I am trying to Deserialize a xml file of this type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Network>
 <ROUTES>
  <ROUTE ID="RT_BALA_GLNC_R_162_154_1" DIRECTION="LEFT" ZONE="Richmond_Hill">
     <ENTRANCESIGNAL>BALA_GLNC_G162</ENTRANCESIGNAL>
     <EXITSIGNAL>BALA_DONS_G154</EXITSIGNAL>
     <POINTENDIDS>
        <POINTENDID POS="N">PT_BALA_GLNC_W11.TrackPortionConnection</POINTENDID>
        <POINTENDID POS="N">PT_BALA_GLNC_W23.TrackPortionConnection</POINTENDID>
     </POINTENDIDS>
  </ROUTE>
  <ROUTE ID="RT_BALA_ORLS_R_111_119_1" DIRECTION="RIGHT" ZONE="Richmond_Hill">
     <ENTRANCESIGNAL>BALA_ORLS_G111</ENTRANCESIGNAL>
     <EXITSIGNAL>BALA_ORLN_G119</EXITSIGNAL>
     <POINTENDIDS>
        <POINTENDID POS="N">PT_BALA_ORLS_W1.TrackPortionConnection</POINTENDID>
     </POINTENDIDS>
  </ROUTE>
  <ROUTE ID="RT_BALA_GLNC_R_162D_154_1" DIRECTION="LEFT" ZONE="Richmond_Hill">
     <ENTRANCESIGNAL>BALA_GLNC_G162D</ENTRANCESIGNAL>
     <EXITSIGNAL>BALA_DONS_G154</EXITSIGNAL>
     <POINTENDIDS>
        <POINTENDID POS="R">PT_BALA_GLNC_W11.TrackPortionConnection</POINTENDID>
        <POINTENDID POS="N">PT_BALA_GLNC_W23.TrackPortionConnection</POINTENDID>
     </POINTENDIDS>
  </ROUTE>
 </ROUTES>
</Network>
```

I have tried this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Network));
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"xml File Location");
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Network XmlData = (Network)obj;
        reader.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
[XmlRoot("Network")]
public class Network
{
    [XmlElement("ROUTES")]
    public List<ROUTE> ROUTES { get; set; }
}

public class ROUTE
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("DIRECTION")]
    public string DIRECTION { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ENTRANCESIGNAL")]
    public string ENTRANCESIGNAL { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("EXITSIGNAL")]
    public string EXITSIGNAL { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("POINTENDIDS")]
    public POINTENDIDS POINTENDIDS { get; set; }
}

public class POINTENDIDS
{
    [XmlElement("POINTENDID")]
    public List<POINTENDID> POINTENDID { get; set; }
}

public class POINTENDID
{
    [XmlAttribute("POS")]
    public string POS { get; set; }
}
```

I am doing it in a console application,

I started Debugging and put breakpoint on  Network XmlData = (Network)obj;

I've got only 1 ROUTES and the values of "ID", "DIRECTION", "ENTRANCESIGNAL" ...etc are set to Null

being beginner in c# programming , I don't really understand what should I do !

Need help for this implementation

Comment: Case sensitive. Use `[XmlRoot("Network")]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix you Network Class.  The names in square brackets are case sensitive.  You also need to add the Xml array attributes.

```
    [XmlRoot("Network")]
    public class Network
    {
        [XmlArrayItem("ROUTE")]
        [XmlArray("ROUTES")]
        public List<ROUTE> ROUTES { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, now I'm getting the expected results :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Xml; //XmlDoc
using System.Xml.Linq;//XElement
using System.IO;//Path,File,Directory, Stream
```

Read and parse xml file:

```
XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDoc.Load(XmlFilePath);
```

Another approach is using `XElement` instead:

```
XElement a = XElement.Load(@"c:\path\file");
```

Most often I prefer XElement over XmlDocument, but that's personal

If you are starting with C#, you'd need a book, and a simpler project. Streams and Xml are syntactically complex. Also, console apps are ugly, and Forms apps are not that hard to do with the graphical tools of VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# classes are not exactly aligned with the XML file and the serializer returns only a partial result. What you can do instead if the XML structure is fixed is outlined here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17315863/99804

This then works as you want it to.

You will get the following auto-generated code.
Note: I have cleaned up the output to use auto-properties etc.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
/// <remarks />
[Serializable]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Network
{
    /// <remarks />
    [XmlArrayItem("ROUTE", IsNullable = false)]
    public NetworkROUTE[] ROUTES { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class NetworkROUTE
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string DIRECTION { get; set; }

    public string ENTRANCESIGNAL { get; set; }

    public string EXITSIGNAL { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("POINTENDID", IsNullable = false)]
    public NetworkROUTEPOINTENDID[] POINTENDIDS { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ZONE { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class NetworkROUTEPOINTENDID
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string POS { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```