# Cannot serialize XML from an API response. System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (1, 2).'

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am currently doing a project related to a formula 1 API but sadly I cannot figure out how to serialize my xml content into an object.

The XML I am trying to serialize : https://pastebin.com/nkt9EA1k

My API request and the attempt to serialize it.

```
        client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2022").Result;
        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Wrapper));
        Wrapper wrapper2;
        string result = File.ReadAllText("temp.txt");//hc.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(result))
        {
            wrapper2 = (Wrapper)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        if(wrapper2 != null)
        {
            SecondWrapper wrapper = wrapper2.MRData;
            string outPut = wrapper.Season;
            foreach (Race r in wrapper.RaceTable)
            {
                outPut += $"\n{r.RaceName}\t{r.Date}\t{r.Circuit.CircuitName}";
            }
            File.WriteAllText("Output.txt", outPut);
        }
```

My Wrapper class :

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public SecondWrapper MRData;
}
```

My SecondWrapper Class :

```
public class SecondWrapper
{
    public string Season;
    public Race[] RaceTable;
}
```

My Race class :

```
public class Race
{
    public string RaceName { set; get; }
    public Circuit Circuit { set; get; }
    public string Date;
    public string Time;
    public StepDateTime FirstPractice { set; get; }
    public StepDateTime SecondPractice { set; get; }
    public StepDateTime ThirdPractice { set; get; }
    public StepDateTime Qualifying { set; get; }
    public StepDateTime Sprint { set; get; }
}
```

My Circuit class :

```
public class Circuit
{
    public string CircuitName { set; get; }
    public Location Location { set; get; }
}
```

My Location class :

```
public class Location
{
    public double lat { set; get; }
    [XmlAttribute("long")]
    public double Long { set; get; }
    public string Locality { set; get; }
    public string Country { set; get; }
}
```

My StepDateTime class :

```
public class StepDateTime
{
    public string Date { set; get; }
    public string Time { set; get; }
}
```

I tried to make a text file where I deleted the first 2 lines of the XML answer hoping it would fix the issue but it didn't.

PS : I know I'm not using propreties and I am not respecting the c# conventions for the classes but it is temporary just so I can find a way to fix the issue. It is also my first time working with xml answers so I might have done some obvious errors.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: .NET has an XSD tool that allows you to generate a schema and then C# classes for the schema instead of having to rely on writing the C# yourself.

Comment: Your classes don't correspond do your XML.  You can auto-generate your classes from the XML as shown in [Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203540).  For instance if I upload your XML to https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ I get a plausible set of classes.  You will need to deserialize to `[XmlRoot(ElementName="MRData", Namespace="http://ergast.com/mrd/1.5")] public class MRData { /* Properties omitted */ }`