# Possible to take Flat XML File and Make it into Complex Classes?

Tags: c#, xml, yaxlib

Say I have something like this

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

is it possible use the YAXLib to Deserialize it into something like this

```
public class Note 
{
  public string to {get; set;}
  public string from {get; set;}
  public string Info {get; set;}
}

public class Info 
{
   public string header {get; set;}
   public string body {get; set;}
}
```

Is there any setting that I can change the pathing to make it go into my C# classes that I setup?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17315863/1188513 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203551/1188513

Comment: Though that is interesting I am trying to figure out how to use the YAXLib to take that xml file and use it deserialization into the classes I written.

Comment: I notice your class `Note` has a `string Info`.  What are you expecting that string to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant for the classes to look like so:

```cs
public class Note
{
    public string to { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string heading { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
}
```

It seems the absolute simplest way to get what you want would be to have two separate deserializers. One for `Info` and one for `Note` and then deserialize (skipping errors for missing element) and stitch the two objects together yourself, like so:

```
Note GetNoteFromXml(string xml)
{
    var noteSer = new YAXSerializer<Note>(new SerializerOptions
    {
        ExceptionHandlingPolicies = YAXExceptionHandlingPolicies.DoNotThrow
    });
    var infoSer = new YAXSerializer<Info>();

    var note = noteSer.Deserialize(xml);
    var info = infoSer.Deserialize(xml);
    note.Info = info;
    return note;
}
```

```
var xml = @"<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>";

var note = GetNoteFromXml(xml);
```