# XmlSerializer throws System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (3, 2).'

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api, xmlserializer

I have an API function to upload xml files and it will return it as a object. It's made to read Italy's digital invoice (which is basically an xml file) but it says it's invalid.

```
InvalidOperationException: <FatturaElettronica xmlns='http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2'> was not expected.
```

The function is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostFile(IFormFile upload)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FatturaElettronica));
        Stream memStream = upload.OpenReadStream();
        FatturaElettronica fe = (FatturaElettronica)ser.Deserialize(memStream);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Where FatturaElettronica is the xml model/class. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Dnx1sFPs) is the xml sample I used.

And here is the class (the first part)

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace backEnd.Models
{
    [XmlRoot("FatturaElettronica")]
    public class FatturaElettronica
    {
        [XmlElement("FatturaElettronicaHeader")]
        public FatturaElettronicaHeader FatturaElettronicaHeader { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("FatturaElettronicaBody")]
        public FatturaElettronicaBody[] FatturaElettronicaBody { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which contains sub-classes like FatturaElettronicaHeader (structured like the xml file)

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace backEnd.Models
{ 
    public class FatturaElettronicaHeader
    {
        [XmlElement("DatiTrasmissione")]
        public DatiTrasmissione DatiTrasmissione { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("CedentePrestatore")]
        public CedentePrestatore CedentePrestatore { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RappresentanteFiscale")]
        public RappresentanteFiscale? RappresentanteFiscale { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("CessionarioCommittente")]
        public CessionarioCommittente CessionarioCommittente { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TerzoIntermediarioOSoggettoEmittente")]
        public TerzoIntermediarioOSoggettoEmittente? TerzoIntermediarioOSoggettoEmittente { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("SoggettoEmittente")]
        public string? SoggettoEmittente { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the XML in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I already did, but [here](https://pastebin.com/Dnx1sFPs) it is

Comment: There is a namespace on the root element, the `[XmlRoot("FatturaElettronica")]` needs to take that into account with e.g. `[XmlRoot(Namespace="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2",ElementName="FatturaElettronica")]`.

Comment: Now it doesn't throw an exception but neighter the header (FatturaElettronicaHeader) or the body gets serialized, they just set to null

Comment: Then I would suggest using one of the tools from [Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203540/3744182) to generate your model, rather than trying to manually create c# classes corresponding to your XML.