# C# Deserialize XML - Issues with Attribute in XML-Tag

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the problem, that I try to deserialize XML into C# using System.Xml.Serialization. The problem seems to be the `<Value>`-Tag. The XML is the following:

```
<Value xsi:type="xs:int" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">0</Value>
```

I tried to deserialize with the following Class:

```
public class Template 
{
    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public TemplateValue Value {get; set;} 
}

public class TemplateValue
{
    [XmlAttribute("type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string type {get; set;}

    [XmlText]
    public string Value {get; set;}    
}
```

Comment: type is a keyword in c#.  Try putting an underscore in front of the variable name : public string _type {get; set;}

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and I'm sure this is helpful :-). Unfortunately it's still not going through the class.

Comment: Common reasons for not going through 1) Namespace, maybe the default 2) Spelling error or Upper/Lower Case 3) Not Public 4) there is an attribute 'type' which means there is an inherited class 4) Item is an array

Comment: `xsi:type` has special meaning, it tells the deserializer what type the actual value is. You don't need any of this, just declare in the parent class `[XmlElement("Value")] public int? Value {get; set;}`. When in doubt, use VS's Paste As XML https://stackoverflow.com/a/17315863/14868997

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I have an XML File which I handle as an array where the type can change for each value. Is there a proper way ro handle this?

Comment: Maybe declare it as `[XmlElement("Value")] public object? Value {get; set;}`

Comment: Is the `<Value>` tag the root document tag, or some nested tag?

Comment: Declaring as `object?`worked well. Thank you all a lot :-)