Map xml element to clr type
Is there any way to map custom processing instruction <?code MySimpleCode?> to a CLR type?
For example - source:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <?code MySimpleCode?>
</root>

Destination
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement(???)]
    public TYPE??? Code { get; set; }
}


Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203540/generate-c-sharp-class-from-xml?

XML Schemas you should go
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/mapping-xml-data-types-to-clr-types
and  con you please check (for imagine whats possible in both ways convertion)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022

For working with XML some find more useful using XDocument from System.Xml.Linq namespace.
Assuming that you will provide correctly structured XML (not the exactly as in provided example), you could use below code:
var raw = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<root>
  <code MySimpleCode=""""></code>
</root>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(raw);

var codeNode = xDoc.Descendants("root").Descendants("code").First();
var mySimpleCode = codeNode.Attribute("MySimpleCode").Value;


NO option to modify source XML
